# Having issues with my loop code and it does not work correctly?

Tags: javascript

I have been asked to make a prompt to enter your current weight and target weight. The loop should calculate how many weeks it will take to reach target weight at loss of 1.38 a week. My prompts work but the loop breaks the javascript. My code is below, can someone help me out? I am new to javscript by the way.

```
 var current_weight = prompt("Please enter your current weight",0.0);
 var target_weight = prompt("Please enter your target weight",0.0);
 var weeks = 0;

 if(current_weight > 0 target_weight > 0){
     if(current_weight > target_weight){
     while(current_weight <= target weight){
         var current_weight =  current_weight – 1.38;
          weeks = weeks + 1;
         alert("it will take" + weeks + "weeks to hit target");
      }
 }

 else if(current_weight > 0 && target_weight > 1){
     alert("Current weight must be more than target weight");
 }


 else{ 
     alert("Input error")
 }

</script>
```

The loop breaks the javascript.

Comment: if current_weight > target_weight, why would the while (current_weight <= target_weight) ever evaluate to true? recheck your logic and adjust the conditions accordingly.

Comment: Hi interesting, so both conditions can't be true so the loop won't execute. `if (current_weight > target_weight) {while( current_weight <= target weight) { ...`

Comment: Is some logic operator missing in if(current_weight > 0 target_weight > 0){ ?

Answer (score 1):

4 problems in your code:

- missing `&&` operator between the conditions in first if statement
- prompt returns the user entered value as string. So you can't subtract `1.38` from `current_weight` as `current_weight` will be a string. You need to convert user entered values in to numbers
- There's a logical error in your code. You have this if statement `if(current_weight > target_weight)` and if it evaluates to true, then `while loop` checks `while(current_weight <= target weight)` which is opposite to the condition of the wrapping if statement. Consequently, your loop will never run. You probably want loop condition to be `current_weight > target_weight`
- alert should be outside the while loop

```js
var current_weight = Number(prompt("Please enter your current weight", 0.0));
var target_weight = Number(prompt("Please enter your target weight", 0.0));
var weeks = 0;

if (current_weight > 0 && target_weight > 0) {

  if (current_weight > target_weight) {
    while (current_weight > target_weight) {
      current_weight = current_weight - 1.38;
      weeks = weeks + 1;
    }

    alert("it will take" + weeks + "weeks to hit target");

  } else if (current_weight > 0 && target_weight > 1) {
    alert("Current weight must be more than target weight");
  } else {
    alert("Input error");
  }
}
```